# I flashed my router to dd-wrt now I can't flash it back

Tags: dd-wrt

I recently got my old TL-WR741ND v2 TP-Link router out and decided to flash the newest beta on it. After doing I noticed that the Wireless Security settings stopped working and WiFi would fail completely. I tried reflashing my firmware to old firmware, but the dialog just keeps on loading with no progress... How can I fix this? I want to go back to a compatible dd-wrt build or revert to factory stock firmware if possible.

Comment: What model is your router?

Comment: @harrymc edited the question to contain this information

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Comment: Not really and I'm not willing to flash some random firmware from the untrusted sources either...

Answer (score 2):

The downloadable firmware from the TP-Link website may contain a bootloader section
in front of the actual firmware, which confuses DD-WRT.

To aid in extracting the right section of the firmware, one person has created
a unofficial compendium of stripped-down TP-Link firmware:
[TP-Link stripped firmware](https://www.friedzombie.com/tplink-stripped-firmware/).

This page contains a link to the stripped
[TL-WR741ND V2 firmware](https://www.friedzombie.com/tplink-stripped-firmware/download.php?d=TL-WR741ND-V2).

Unzip the downloaded file and try to use DD-WRT to install the included `.bin` file.

Comment: hmm the problem appears to be not the bootloader, because I can't flash a different revision of dd-wrt onto it either...

Comment: The problem with DD-WRT is locating the right firmware. Installing doesn't work either with the firmware in my answer?

Comment: I tried using the official "revert back to stock" firmware from dd-wrt website and it did not work. either did a different build of dd-wrt build, hence my scepsis. I will try out your suggested firmware later when I have some extra time

Comment: Is there a way to strip down the firmware by myself? With binwalk or smth?

Comment: You need to cut the first 0x20200 bytes (131,584 = 257*512), for example with `dd if=orig.bin of=tplink.bin skip=257 bs=512`. This was already done in my first link, so I would recommend trying it first.

Comment: I used the command you supplied to me and it did not work. What did work is sshing into the device and running `wget` to get the firmware file and `write /path/to/bin.bin linux` to flash the image. Something was wrong with the web UI.